# Obtener un máximo valor asociado a un mes

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, select, subconsultas

intento cubrir una consulta sql que me solicita el máximo de puntos (de un alumno) por cada mes. (PD: Los puntos para un alumno se obtienen mediante trabajos que realizan, con fines de caridad a un compañero). El avance que he realizado previamente, me permite llegar a esta salida en consola:

```
   id_alumno    | año  | mes |  puntos_alumno
----------------+------+-----+----------------
            631 | 2021 |   6 |              9
            961 | 2020 |   5 |             10
            294 | 2021 |   5 |             14
            345 | 2020 |   6 |             12
            552 | 2021 |   6 |             20
            432 | 2020 |   5 |             17
            751 | 2021 |   5 |             18
            700 | 2020 |   4 |             15
            217 | 2020 |   5 |             21
            208 | 2021 |   6 |             29
            405 | 2021 |   4 |             24
            431 | 2020 |   4 |             35
            129 | 2021 |   4 |             20
```

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente, es decir, que alumno logró mas puntos asociados al trabajo que realizó durante un mes en específico:

```
      id        | año  | mes |  maximo puntos
----------------+------+-----+----------------
            431 | 2020 |   4 |             35
            217 | 2020 |   5 |             21
            345 | 2020 |   6 |             12
            129 | 2021 |   4 |             20
            751 | 2021 |   5 |             18
            208 | 2021 |   6 |             29
```

Lo que llevo es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT b1.id, date_part('year',b1.fecha) as Año, date_part('month',b1.fecha) as Mes, max(b2) as "puntos"
FROM(
  select P.id_presupuesto,count(D.tarea_finalizada) b2,P.fecha 
  from "Presupuesto" P 
  inner join "Detalle_Trabajo" D on P.orden = D.orden 
  where (date_part('year',CURRENT_DATE)-date_part('year',P.fecha)) < 2 
  group by P.id order by P.id ASC
    ) as b1
  GROUP BY b1.id, b1.fecha
  ORDER BY Año DESC;
```

Sin embargo, no logro obtener el máximo para cada mes. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la versión de SQL Server te lo permite, puedes hacer algo así:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    select P.id_presupuesto,
           date_part('year', P.fecha) as Año,
           date_part('month', P.fecha) as Mes,
           count(D.tarea_finalizada) as 'maximo puntos',
           row_number() over (partition by date_part('year', P.fecha), date_part('month', P.fecha) order by count(D.tarea_finalizada) DESC) as Rn
           FROM Presupuesto P 
           INNER JOIN Detalle_Trabajo D 
              ON P.orden = D.orden 
           WHERE (date_part('year',CURRENT_DATE)-date_part('year',P.fecha)) < 2
)
SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Rn = 1;
```

Simplemente, generamos un numerador, la columna `Rn` con `Row_number()` que se reinicia con cada grupo de año/mes y está ordenado par la cantidad de puntos de mayor a menor. Puedes usar una subconsulta, o en este ejemplo una "common table expression" que es algo parecido, filtrar finalmente las primeras filas de cada grupo nos retornaría la fila deseada.